# Need help to convert ECG data from EDF format to TXT format in Python

Tags: python, txt, european-data-format

I can need to convert ECG edf file to text format in PYTHON. Can not do it. Tried a lot. plz help me someone.

by using pyedflib getting this traceback:

:Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/shafi/anaconda3/envs/NEW37/Lib/encodings/rd_edf_py.py", line 8, in  sigbufs=np.zeros((n, f.getSignalLabels()[0])) TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

*******************actual code is below*********************

```
import pyedflib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f= pyedflib.EdfReader( 'C:\\Users\\shafi\\PycharmProjects\\pyHrv\\Sample.edf')
n=f.signals_in_file 
signal_labels=f.getSignalLabels()
sigbufs=np.zeros((n, f.getSignalLabels()[0])) 
fig=plt.figure()
ax=plt.axes() 
for i in np.arange(n):
    sigbufs[i, :] = f.readSignal(i) 
    ax.plot(f.readSignal(i))
    x.plot(f.readSignal(i)) 
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, post an example of the input you are using. Also, share your efforts so people could help you better. Your question is too vague.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pyedflib](https://github.com/holgern/pyedflib): it is a library useful for your case, for example to [read](https://github.com/holgern/pyedflib/blob/master/demo/readEDFFile.py) a `.edf` file.

Once you have read your `.edf` file, you can save every array through simple `numpy` commands such as `numpy.savetxt()`.

Comment: thank you very much. however I am getting an error. Is this because the edf file has a problem in it ? i am adding the code in next comment

Comment: Can you edit your post adding your latest comments?

Comment: can i do the same thong with mne in python ?

Comment: I did it please check my equation